# simple covariance homework question

Tags: covariance

any help is greatly appreciated. I am insecure about whether and how to use the covariance formula for this basic question.

Suppose X is a random variable with E[X]=E[X^3]=0. Suppose that Y=X^2 is another random variable.

a) What is cov[X,Y]?
b) Is X independent of Y?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written down the definition of $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ and plugged in $Y=X^2$? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have, I just have trouble reading the the chain of E[X]=E[X^3]=0. It literally means the expected value of X is equal to the expected value of X^3 is equal to zero. So because Y=X^2 and is multiplied by X in the formula you can E[X^3] which is 0, yes?

Answer (score 0):

$cov [X,Y]=EXY-EX EY=EX^{3}-EXEX^{2}=0-0=0$.

$X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $X=\pm c$ with probaility $1/2$ each for some $c$. This is because independence of $X$ and $Y$ implies that $Y$ is independent of itself so it is  a constant.

Comment: ok so you get 0 - 0 in your last step because E[X^3] is already defined as equal to 0 yes?

Comment: @introvertsdoitbetter Yes, that is right.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the first part
\begin{eqnarray*}
Cov(X,Y) =E[XY]-E[X]E[Y].
\end{eqnarray*}
Hint for the second part: What does $Cov[X,Y]=0$ tell us about how $X$ & $Y$ are correlated?

Comment: Uncorrelated random variables need not be independent.

Comment: would it be best to answer part b of this question (is X independent of Y) by stating that just because cov[X,Y] is 0, does not imply the two random variables are in fact independent of each other?